# Finding an index with certain conditions

Tags: list-manipulation

EDIT: I need to find out an index `i` which depends on certain conditions and I'm not able to implement it. I have a list (time points) $t_i$ and two constants $a,c$ the length of the list $t_i$ is $n$.

So now I want to find the index $1 \leq i < n$, which can be found according to  $t_{n-i}+a<c<t_{n-(i+1)}$ where $t_0:=\infty$.

For example I know that `i=5`in this example, but I would like to have a function which tells me that:

```
c = 0.07875`
a = 0.01125`
ti = {0.056249999999999994`, 0.045`, 0.03375`, 0.0225`, 0.01125`, 0.`}
n=6
```

Do you have any tips how to implement it?

Comment: @rainer, In your example the first element of `ti` is not infinity. What is $t_0:=\infty$ supposed to be?

Comment: It's difficult for me to explain it properly but i try my best: if `n-(i+1)=0` we have `t_0`which does not exist so we set it to Infinity. Basically I did a coordination transformation and need to find the index (time) in the new system between which `ti`s my c is.

Comment: rainer, with your new indexing, "I know that `j=5` ..." should change to  "I know that `j=6` ..."?

Comment: mho, no actually it should be `i=5`, because if `i=6` i would get `t_(n-i-1)=t_(-1)`which would make no sense,`i`should be lower than n.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 Pick[#, ti[[n - (# - 1)]] + a < c < If[# == n, Infinity, ti[[n - (#)]]] & /@ #]&[Range[Length[ti]]]
```

or

```
 Select[Range[Length[ti]], ti[[n - (# - 1)]] + a < c < If[# == n, Infinity, ti[[n - (#)]]] &]   
 (* {6} *)
```

Comment: Thanks, I figured out how to do it with your first solution!

Answer (score 3):

I'm really not sure I understand your question but maybe by pure luck I'll hit upon something that helps you.

```
c = 0.07875`
a = 0.01125`
ti = {0.056249999999999994`, 0.045`, 0.03375`, 0.0225`, 0.01125`, 0.`};

AppendTo[ti, ∞]

Position[
 # + a < c < #2 & @@@ Partition[ti, 2, 1],
 True
]
```

> ```
> {{6}}
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Can create a large surrogate for infinity and use a zero-order interpolation.

```
inf = 10.^10;

func = Interpolation[
   Transpose[{Prepend[data, inf], Range[Length[data], 0, -1]}]
   , InterpolationOrder -> 0];
```

Exampless:

```
c = 0.07875`;
a = 0.01125`;

func[.04]

(* Out[122]= 4. *)

func[a + c]

(* Out[123]= 6. *)
```

For large data sets this method will be generally faster than linear search approaches. For example, try it on

```
data2 = Accumulate[RandomReal[1, 10^6]];
```